# Xamarin android: Async await calls not working when app open by clicking push notification

Tags: firebase, xamarin.android, async-await, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I open app by tapping on FCM push notification, The API service calls I am making by using `await` keyword those are not working. Entire app not returning data.
Code for API calling

```
var result = await objHomework.GetHomeWorksForStudentPagesAsync(studentId.ToString());
```

result returning `null`. if app already open, everything working fine. See the Image below [screenshot of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9chOK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was missing some keys which is necessary for service call authentication in my project. I am getting those keys in MaiActivity but notification click even starting app from somewhere else therefore keys values was null and service calls was not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Notification messages are delivered to `OnMessageReceived` callback only when the app is in the foreground.

Override the `HandleIntent` Method of the `FirebaseMessageService` to work for background as well

```
public override void HandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    try
    {
        if (intent.Extras != null)
        {
            var builder = new RemoteMessage.Builder("MyFirebaseMessagingService");

            foreach (string key in intent.Extras.KeySet())
            {
                builder.AddData(key, intent.Extras.Get(key).ToString());
            }

            this.OnMessageReceived(builder.Build());
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleIntent(intent);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        base.HandleIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: @iamlcarus, OnMessageReceived calling every time for me. But the issue is when i open foreground app by tapping notifications, app is opening specific screen but nothing working, like not fetching data from services.